# Kali Linux installation on Macbook Air

Tags: linux, macos, macbook, kali-linux, macbook-air

I am using MacBook Air (early 2015) and I can't boot Kali Linux.

I have already tried Ubuntu, same procedure as for Kali:

- Partition the USB drive
- Use dd command to burn the ISO file
- Reboot with option key down

Ubuntu is working as intended, but when I try to boot KALI LINUX I either get blank (black) screen or once in a while the grub appears (in top left corner and cannot select any option, it is frozen).

Any suggestions? Is something wrong with KALI image since I can run other Linux Distros.

Thank you.

[Screenshot of Kali gurb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGJN3.jpg)

After 2-3 reboots, Kali boots this, but is frozen. Can't select anything.

Comment: I managed to boot on an older version of Backtrack with EFI But impossible with Kali Linux for my Macbook Air

Comment: So no way to install it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment.

Did you try to use your bootable drive on others computers ?

If you use a usb keyboard,check that you BIOS have the option "USB keyboard support" "Enabled".

Then try usb disk creators: unetbootin,multisystem,...

After making your bootable drive,check that everything is ok in the logs.

Comment: I did not try on other computers. I am not using USB keyboard. I used Mac Linux USB creator and same result. No errors after making a bootable drive.

Comment: Then,can you try?

Comment: Sure. I will try when I reach home. I created Ubuntu bootable drive the same way I did for Kali and it worked. It must be something Kali/Debian specific. Something grafic related.

Comment: Ok,and then would you please edit your post.Also did you try other graphical usb disk creators?

Comment: I used the same USB on another laptop and everything works just fine, but still no success on macbook.

Comment: Try with a live-dvd,for some machines boot is better on cd/dvd than on usb.